# how we can go and go back into a user controller docked fill on the form on keeping the state?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have form were I display menu on top and a panel docked fill on the rest of body.

And for each item of menu I display a user control in the panel and move the precedent user control.

My question is how can I switch between the user control and keep the same state as when I switch in other user controls.

Comment: I have a thread modifying a progress bar inside a user controller, but when I go to another user controller and came back I had a new instance of the user controller and the progress stop uploading from the thread

Comment: You should edit your question rather than commenting on it.

Answer (score 0):

This might be better as a comment, but having to post as an answer until I get more rep. If the progress value is stored in the control object, you need to save that control's instance in a variable in your form (or somewhere outside the control itself so that specific control instance is saved). When updating the value, access the control through your saved instance.

Or you could save the progress value in your form (to retain state), and the control would use that variable for displaying the progress.

Edit: Without seeing your current code, it's hard to know what's going on. But generally you're better off keeping your worker thread(s) isolated from form controls, so it doesn't block the UI, and using events to update a control when needed. If the control is created in the same form as the thread that updates the progress value variable, it can still access it using 'this' form instance.